# Colorfinder.js error

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use `colorfinder.js` to set the background color of a curtain div to the most prominent color in the `img` for each `li`. The code works fine when I just give `rgb` a set value, but `colorfinder.js` returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.    

$('ul li').each(function(){
        var $a = $('a', this);
        var $img = $('img', this);
        var rgb = new ColorFinder().getMostProminentColor( $img );
        var $div = $('<div class="curtain"></div>');
        ($div).css('background-color', 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
        $a.append($div);



    });
```

Comment: You give an jQuery object as a parameter to ColorFinder. I guess it expects just the image, so try `.getMostProminentColor( $img ).get(0);`.

Comment: That returns:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naturalHeight' of undefined

Comment: Is `$img` actually set? Could you maybe provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: one mistake in my first comment - I meant: `.getMostProminentColor( $img.get(0) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you pass to the `ColorFinder` instance is actually not an image, but a jQuery object. ColorFinder doesn't accept a jQuery object here, so you have to pass the actual image.

You can get the DOM elements a jQuery object refers to by using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/). So to get the first (maybe only) image within that `<li>` elements, use this:

```
// ...
var rgb = new ColorFinder().getMostProminentColor( $img.get(0) );
// ...
```

For completeness sake: One should check before, if there is actually an element returned in the jQuery object:

```
// ...
if( $img.length > 0 ) {
  var rgb = new ColorFinder().getMostProminentColor( $img.get(0) );
  var $div = $('<div class="curtain"></div>');
  ($div).css('background-color', 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
  $a.append($div);
}
// ...
```